# Web scraping with R - can't avoid error 403

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm working on my HW, i need to scrape date of review, score and time of usage, but it's not the problem. Problem is that website detects somehow webdriver even though special site to check says that it can't detect webdriver. I attach code and screenshots. Help please :) Any ideas what to add to eCaps? Do i need proxies?

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(wdman)
library(RSelenium)

rD$server$stop()
eCaps <- list(
  chromeOptions = list(
    args = c('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled','--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.6045.105 Safari/537.36','--remote-allow-origins=*'),
    prefs = list(
      "credentials_enable_service" = TRUE,
      "profile.password_manager_enabled" = FALSE
    )
  )
)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever="119.0.6045.105",port = 4445L, extraCapabilities = eCaps)
remDr <- rD$client



url<-"https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/chrome-headless-test.html"
url2<-"https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/3b19417d3012ed20/61-smartfon-apple-iphone-14-pro-128-gb-fioletovyj/opinion/"

remDr$navigate(url2)

#remDr$navigate(url2)
status<-remDr$getStatus()
status

html_source <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
file_name <- "dns.html"
write(html_source, file_name)
```

"url" is website to check webdriver and other get other tests
"url2" is website where from i should collect some data

Code for scraping:

```
for (page_num in 1:5) {
  remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", value = paste0(".paginator-widget__page[data-page-number='", page_num, "']"))$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(2) # Wait for page to load

  # Get the HTML content of the current page
  html_content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
  page <- read_html(html_content)

  # Extract specific data
  dates <- page %>% html_nodes(".ow-opinion__site") %>% html_text()
  ratings <- page %>% html_nodes(".star-rating__stars") %>% html_text() # Further processing may be needed
  comments <- page %>% html_nodes(".ow-opinion__info-desc") %>% html_text()

  # Combine the extracted data into a data frame
  page_results <- data.frame(Date = dates, Rating = ratings, Comment = comments)

  all_results[[page_num]] <- page_results
}
```

Thank you!

I've tried to add special capabilities for crawler, didn't try to use proxies.